# How to create code segement size should be in 16 mb ( in byte code) size c++ program

Tags: c++, c

I am looking find out the ways to creat in code segement size should be 16 mb (c++ byte code size is 16 MB)

Comment: i hope person doesnt understand the question doing down vote

Comment: Since you've notice that your question was not very clear can you add some clarification and tell what are you trying to achieve? (Aslo the must would be to have which toolchain your are using)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy and paste 16MB of nop instruction in __asm{} in a function . And dont use that function. Each nop must be 1-Byte. Then you will have the thing. Dynamically code-changing mechanisms you will need then.

You will copy 1 nop into the 2 nops. then copy 2 nops into 4 nops. untill you do this for 24 times(24 bit equals 16 million differents am i right?)

i was forgetting to tell you that you need to disable some optimizations for that. Or you can just use digital mars all optimizations turned off.

Suggest you to do this in a separate file.(maybe include )

If you want the linking be quicker, you should make it 16-Byte aligned.

Sample of main_program.cpp

```
#include<your_16MB_nop>
#include<....
....
int main(){/* whatever here */}
```

Sample of your_16MB_nop

```
void func_never_used_directly()
{
    __asm
        {
         nop
         nop
         nop
         ... 16million times(just copy and paste each last block for 24 times)
         nop 
         }
 }
```

Comment: can you give me a sample c++ code for that please ..